# How to "save" my JS styles in LocalStorage?

Tags: javascript, function, local-storage

I put on my blog the option to change the style of some divs by clicking buttons (*to light, dark and defaul theme*). To get better, I need when the visitor chooses one, that style gets saved in the localStorage, but I do not know how to do it.
I've tried a lot by looking at examples on the internet but none fit my case and I got lost.
here's my code:

**Bottons with onclick functions**:

```
<button onClick="lightTheme()" class="button light">Light</button>
<button onClick="grayTheme()" class="button default">Default</button>
<button onClick="darkTheme()" class="button dark">Dark</button>
```

**MY FULL JAVASCRIPT:**

```
  function lightTheme(){
  var ele = document.getElementsByClassName('picArea');
  for (var i = 0; i < ele.length; i++ ) {
  ele[i].style.backgroundColor = "#EEE";
  ele[i].style.borderColor = "#000";
  }
  var ele = document.getElementsByClassName('picTitle');
  for (var i = 0; i < ele.length; i++ ) {
  ele[i].style.color = "#111";
  }
  var ele = document.getElementsByClassName('picNumber');
  for (var i = 0; i < ele.length; i++ ) {
  ele[i].style.backgroundColor = "#AAA";
  ele[i].style.color = "#111";
  }
}

function darkTheme(){
  var ele = document.getElementsByClassName('picArea');
  for (var i = 0; i < ele.length; i++ ) {
  ele[i].style.backgroundColor = "#222";
  ele[i].style.borderColor = "#000";
  }
  var ele = document.getElementsByClassName('picTitle');
  for (var i = 0; i < ele.length; i++ ) {
  ele[i].style.color = "#fff";
  }
  var ele = document.getElementsByClassName('picNumber');
  for (var i = 0; i < ele.length; i++ ) {
  ele[i].style.backgroundColor = "#";
  ele[i].style.color = "#EEE";
  }
}

function grayTheme(){
  var ele = document.getElementsByClassName('picArea');
  for (var i = 0; i < ele.length; i++ ) {
  ele[i].style.backgroundColor = "#777";
  ele[i].style.borderColor = "#000";
  }
  var ele = document.getElementsByClassName('picTitle');
  for (var i = 0; i < ele.length; i++ ) {
  ele[i].style.color = "#fff";
  }
  var ele = document.getElementsByClassName('picNumber');
  for (var i = 0; i < ele.length; i++ ) {
  ele[i].style.backgroundColor = "#555";
  }
}
```

**...and if helps:**

**My divs on HTML:**

```
<div class="picArea"><p class="picTitle">Picture X<span class="picNumber">1</span></p></div>
<div class="picArea"><p class="picTitle">Picture X<span class="picNumber">2</span></p></div>
<div class="picArea"><p class="picTitle">Picture X<span class="picNumber">3</span></p></div>
```

**CSS (only for the demo):**

```
.picArea {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background: #777;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px 0;
}
.picTitle {
    font-size: 150%;
    margin: 0;
    color: #fff;
}
.picNumber {
    padding: 0 7px;
    background: #555;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    color: #ccc;
    font-size: 80%;
}
.button {
    width: 75px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: none;
}
.button.light {
    background: #ccc;
    color: #000;
}
.button.dark {
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
.button.default {
    background: #777;
    color: #fff;
}
```

A preview: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncneS.jpg

Comment: This is probably not the best way to do it. You should just toggle body class with JS and do the styling with CSS.

Comment: @MladenIlić ToggleClass with Jquery? I'll try ... but to save them in LocalStorage, can you give an example?

Comment: Adding it as answer, can't add code snippets here. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better approach would be to toggle data attribute on body and use it to style the content with CSS:

https://jsfiddle.net/bt3qh8L1/2/ (had to add fiddle, SO snippets do not allow usage of `localStorage`).

You can use `localStorage.setItem('key', 'value');` and `localStorage.getItem('key');` to store and load data from local storage.

Here's more info on Local Storage and the way it works: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage

Cheers.

Comment: Ok, i'm going to read this link. Thank you so much for the answer and the fiddle demo!!

Answer (score 0):

> style gets saved in the localStorage

You have to define what kind of storage you want to use. So if you have registred users you could save that style information in your servers Database.

Or you want to save the information localy in the clients browser? Then we have different options. We can use:

- Cookie
- Session

Comment: No, I have no login system... its a simple blog and i'm not so expert lol

Answer (score 0):

ok you would like to do it localy in the browser. How long you like to save the style information? If the user reloads the page I think you would like to keep the selected style. If the user is closing the browser an open it again, visiting your site, what behaviour you want?

Comment: it would be perfect to keep this as much as can, when the browser also remains safe

Comment: **when the browser is closed